# What is the best way to get business-applicable experience in new languages?

Tags: work-experience, technology

I have a couple of years under my belt as a .NET developer, with C++ and Java mixed in, but I feel I would be hard pressed to get a job in anything but .NET without starting again from the bottom. I'm especially interested in becoming a Scala developer, but while I can teach myself the fundamentals or even take a class, I don't see a way to segue into working in this from my current on-the-job experience.

Comment: Two words: Open Source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Develop an example of your skills.  Pick a relevant project and code it up on your spare time and bring it to interviews on disc including print outs some of your coding in Scala (probably a project summary write-up with the code).  Mention your overall development work and in the job description include your business work.  Then in your resume summary or overview of skills include the years of independent Scala development and the project you did which is available to review upon request.

> As Christopher Estep mentions Open Source projects are a great way to demonstrate your capabilities...find one and join.

This will allow the employer to see you worked professionally in c#/c++ but you have studied to a proficiency level in Scala on your own and have objective proof.  They will likely quiz you and give you a test to be sure you really did do it and didn't copy from someone, but as you have done it that should be rather easy for you to pass as you have the developed skills needed.  Overall development experience is a plus regardless as you will need that to design software anyway.

Comment: Better than bringing it on disc: put it on GitHub. Put your GitHub address on your resume. As an interviewer I don't want to mess with discs and don't want to wait until you hand me something before I see it.

Comment: @SethR very true, if you can check it in publicly then that is an option as well and gets it there with easier access to interviewers.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to aim at a level of (experience + visibility) that gets you hired outside of the usual ad/recruiter-HR-Tech Interview loop. That loop wants to see that someone else paid you to do work in language X for Y years. Generally they don't want to take on the time and trouble of evaluating your open source project or whatever else you're putting forward. If they do, they will hold you to a very high standard compared to the "paid to work in language X for Y years" candidates.

So instead, work on raising **both** your visibility and your experience. Attend meetups. Attend conferences. Join a slack group or whatever the cool kids type at each other with this week. Get active on Twitter and Tumblr and a blog and what not - every time you solve a problem, publish something about how "whatever" works in Scala or what to do when you get "blah blah" error message. When something happens - an announcement, a conference, a big release - tweet and blog the heck out of it. You will learn more this way than you would just coding, and people will start to know who you are. You don't have to start public speaking if you don't want to - just a whole lot of typing while you learn will fill the bill.

Eventually, use your platform to announce you're ready for a Scala opportunity. Someone will want to hire you. Job done.